# How do I make a <ul> into a dropdown menu?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The ASP.NET MVC 5 template that comes with Visual Studio creates this HTML in the _LoginPartial partial view.

It looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <a href="#">@string.Format("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!")</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Change password", "ChangePassword", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Change Password" })
    </li>

    @{
        var o = Session["CurrentUserIsAdmin"];
        if (o != null)
        {
            var currentUserIsAdmin = (bool)o;

            if (currentUserIsAdmin)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Create New Admin User", "Register", "Account",
                    routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Create New Admin User" })
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

It produces this:

[image]

I would like to change it so that:

1) One item, say, **First Item** is shown in the navigation bar.

2) The rest of the items, i.e. the items that you presently see in the navigation bar, i.e all the items that are in the `<ul>` should become a drop-down menu that also sits on the navigation bar just after **First Item**.

I don't know enough CSS and bootstrap to do it myself. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">First item</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                @string.Format("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!")
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Change password", "ChangePassword", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Change Password" })
            </li>
            @{
                var o = Session["CurrentUserIsAdmin"];
                if (o != null)
                {
                    var currentUserIsAdmin = (bool)o;

                    if (currentUserIsAdmin)
                    {
                        <li>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Create New Admin User", "Register", "Account",
                            routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Create New Admin User" })
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
            <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `<ul>` tag to a `<select>` tag and the `<li>` tag into a `<option>` tag